# Setting up a new RoR project using Rspec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to learn RoR following [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) and I'm currently in chapter 3. The tutorial works fine if I follow it line-by-line. However, the commands used in the tutorial suppress generation of default tests. When I try to keep them and possibly use them in my project, I always hit a wall somewhere.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$ rails new myproject
$ cd myproject/
$ echo "gem 'rspec'" >> Gemfile
$ echo "gem 'rspec-rails'" >> Gemfile
$ echo "gem 'capybara'" >> Gemfile
$ bundle install
$ bundle --binstubs
$ rails generate rspec:install
$ rails generate controller StaticPages home help about
```

Then I edit the `spec/views/static_pages/home.html.erb_spec.rb` file, to test whether capybara works:

```
require 'spec_helper'
#require 'capybara'
#require 'capybara/rails'
#require 'capybara/rspec'

describe "static_pages/home.html.erb" do
  it 'should have a right title' do
    visit '/static_pages/home'
    page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Home')
  end
end
```

Running `bin/rspec` at this point, obviously, ends up with a failure. Well, a failure could have been expected. The *reason* for one of these failures is more alarming, though:

```
  1) static_pages/home.html.erb should have a right title
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_5:0x00000003dfd268>
     # ./spec/views/static_pages/home.html.erb_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The `visit` method, which AFAIK is part of Capybara, has not been found. Uncommenting the three extra requires in `home.html.erb_spec.rb` does not change anything in the result.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or what I should do better?

Rails version: 3.2.6

Comment: What happens if you move the `require capybara` into the spec_helper file?

Comment: @ScottJShea The same, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your test in `requests` directory instead of `views`.

Comment: Because you're doing here not a view test, but an integrational test. Views tests are just for testing views rendering in isolation. Hence, by putting your test in `views` folder you didn't provide it with `visit` method, because it isn't used for views tests.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess an even better solution would be using a command from the tutorial I've forgotten about, `rails generate integration_test static_pages`?

Comment: @kamilk It's too long command for such a simple task: just make spec-file in your `requests` dir and put `require 'spec_helper'` inside. Then write your test bellow. There's no need in require of capybara in `spec_helper.rb`. Mentioning it in your `Gemfile` (I assume under `group :test` section) has to be enough.